# How to extend an array with os.path.join (root, filename)

Tags: python, list, join, path, operating-system

When I run the below code in for loop

```
print(os.path.join (root, filename ))
```

It displays properly

But when I do this instead of above

```
G=[ ]
G.extend(os.path.join ( root, filename ))
```

And print `G` after the end of for loop

It didplays each path letter as character list like
`'F',':','\','m','y'....etc`

Plz help

Answer (score 2):

That's what [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html?#array.array.extend) is intended to do.

Are you looking for [`append`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html?#array.array.append) instead?

```
>>> root = 'folder'
>>> filename = 'filename.ext'
>>> os.path.join(root, filename)
'folder\\filename.ext'

>>> g = []
>>> g.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
>>> g
['folder\\filename.ext']
```